# When my work is presented by colleague at conference I don't attend, do I include on my CV?

Tags: publications, cv

My colleague has been presenting our work overseas. I'm primary investigator and first author on the work/papers. Should I or can I be including these presentations on my CV?

My context is that I'm a doctoral student in healthcare discipline and using the CV for grant applications.

Thank you!

Comment: Did your colleagues include you as a co-author on the presentation?

Comment: Are you presenter for any of your work? Is your colleague quite senior compared to you?  In any case, it is usually better to give the impression that you know the difference between what counts more and what counts less (whether the assessment is fair or not). As someone quite junior in your career, you might list the presentation that your colleague is giving on your project since it indicates that the project is active and productive, but distinguish between those that you gave and those that your other colleagues present. (If you were more senior, you'd only give those of your own).

Comment: I would say that for fields in which conference presentations/proceedings are counted as publications the answer would be yes, otherwise no.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes, we always include each other as co-authors. He is quite senior and much more established in his career.

Comment: @Bitwise But even if the conference has proceedings, OP should list the _paper_ in their CV, because they're a coauthor, but _not_ the presentation of that paper, because they didn't present it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Credit for a presentation doesn't go only to the person who gives a talk or presents a poster. Everyone involved in the work should be acknowledged.

The standard practice I've used is credit everybody involved in the research on the poster. So if I give a poster presentation, I include any students, postdocs, or colleagues who collaborated on the research. I also indicate who the presenter was if it wasn't me.

Comment: I'm a little confused by your answer---all but the last sentence seem to be about the crediting non-presenters in the presentation, and then the last sentence seems to be a non-sequitur.  (In my field, the answer to the question would be no.)

Comment: I'm similarly confused with Kimball, since I read the initial parts of this answer as what speaker/presenter must do  *during* the talk/poster. But I wouldn't expect my co-authors to list the presentation on their CV as their own talk, etc. It perhaps is a confusion between fields where the talk/poster presentation must become a publication and those where talks are considered relatively ephemeral and equivalent to a published paper.

Comment: "Credit for a presentation doesn't go only to the person who gives a talk or presents a poster. Everyone involved in the work should be acknowledged." This is a very helpful reminder, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

When research that will be published with multiple names on it is presented by someone, I think the most appropriate thing to do is list all of the names of the people who did the research and mark whoever the person/people who presented it with "(presenter)." For example:

> Alpha, Beta (presenter), and Gamma. *On the Naming Family "-yan"*, Oral Presentation at the North American Conference for Naming Conventions.

I would do this both on listings where you presented and on listings where you didn't. The motivation here is that the *act of giving the presentation* is rarely what you're getting credit for. What you're getting credit for is the research and potentially the fact that you were invited to present the research at the conference. This is true of you even if you weren't the person who went.